# How to get rid of the "share with Instagram contacts" option from iOS Photos?

Tags: ios, photos, sharing, instagram

Using iOS 15.7.6 on an iPod Touch, when I go to any photo in my camera roll and press "share," the very first option listed is a profile picture from a random account I follow on Instagram.  I have never sent any photo to this account and I never will.  I am worried that if I tap on it by accident, the selected photo will immediately be sent to this account without any confirmation (but I'm not going to test this); but even if there is a confirmation dialog, it's annoying having this random profile picture show up when I'm not doing anything with Instagram and don't intend to.

How can I hide the Instagram contacts from the "share" list in Photos so I don't see this all the time?

This is a dedicated list of contacts that appears *above* the list of apps through which I might want to share the picture.  I don't mind Instagram appearing in the list of apps (though I'll probably never share a photo in IG messenger) but I don't want the IG contacts appearing above the app list or appearing at all.

Comment: When I `share`, there’s a `…` to the right of the choices of apps.  Press it and you’ll see a list which you can manipulate by using the `Edit` option (top right).  Just uncheck IG?

Comment: Ah, somehow I had missed that!  I found "edit actions" at the bottom, but I didn't go all the way to the right in the horizontally-scrolling apps list.  Unselecting IG with the little green toggle switch, then closing and reopening the sharing screen, does make the profile picture go away, thanks!  If you want to write up an answer I'll give you the checkmark.